# Android service is not running in my application

Tags: android, service

My service class not running in background i have followed the sample tutorial, dont what is the issue and why its not running?

This is my Service class

```
public class Services extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("OnBind", "OnBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("OnCreate", "OnCreate");

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("OnStart", "OnStart");

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

My Menifest

```
<service
            android:name=".Services"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>
```

MyActivity to call the services

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Services.class));
```

Kindly look it out my coding and help me to run the app properly,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check by providing the whole name of services class like com.example.Services.

Comment: Wow its Working, thanks.  but one more doubt for calling services continuously what i have to do?

Comment: u mean running a service continuously?

Comment: Why do you need that,it will drain your battery.

Comment: Yes exactly,  i need to start the services once my app getting started and it have to run till my app closed.

Comment: i need to listen my API if any data is changed i need to show that in my app, thats why

Comment: you are running in same process or different process? @Brindha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check by providing the whole name of services class like `com.example.Services` rather than `.Services` in your manifest file.

For continiously running the service, do the following :

```
public class YourServiceName extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent i, int startId) {

    this.test.run();
    this.stopSelf();
}

public Runnable test= new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
                // Do something
    }
};
```

}

The AlarmManager that starts it:

```
Intent testService = new Intent(this, YourServiceName .class);
PendingIntent pitestService = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,testService,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pitestService);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000,   pitestService);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i need to stop the services after my application closed. i have used Intent i = new Intent(Favourite.this, Services.class);
    Favourite.this.stopService(i); but its not working. give some idea.

Comment: It should work. Check this example : https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_services